# Connecting to MySQL using IAM Authentication

Tags: mysql, powershell, rds

I was able to connect to my MySQL RDS Instance using the connection string below but how could I utilize IAM authentication instead of manually declaring the user name and password?

```
[void][system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$cn = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnclsection
$cn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=$mysql_server;DATABASE=information_schema;UID=$mysql_user;PWD=$pw"
$cn.Open()
```

So far I have created a user on my DB and granted it IAM authentication. Generated a token and placed it on a variable.

```
$Token = aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname <my_endpoint> --port 3306 --region ap-northeast-2 --username sa
```

Comment: There is no support in AWS Powershell tools for using IAM authentication for RDS connection. Instead of Powershell commands, you can use AWS cli commands.

Comment: Please refer the following link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-iam-authentication-to-connect-with-sql-workbenchj-to-amazon-aurora-mysql-or-amazon-rds-for-mysql/